# how to find out a list of static destructors in a shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld

Our project loads hundreds of shared c++ libraries built by different teams. One of the frequent issues is crashing at exit due to multiple destruction of the same class object. It happens due to (unintentional) sharing instances of the the same class variables between different libs.

The problem is in hunting down the culprit code. Crash stack usually does not show a useful info and running a debugger is difficult and takes time. What would help is an app which could at least list a set of destructors which are called at exit for a particular so lib. I think, it could be possible to get from the .fini_array section. I just wonder if anyone has an experience or can recommend an app to do so. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Linux has *programs*, not 'apps'.

Comment: @Roadowl too many latters :-)

Answer (score 0):

> how to find out a list of static destructors in a shared library

You can disassemble the code and parse calls to `atexit()` inside `__static_initailization_and_destrution_0` function. Like so:

```
$ objdump -CD a.out | awk '/<__static_initialization_and_destruction_0\(int, int\)>/{f=1}  /^$/{f=0}  f && /__cxa_atexit@plt/{print to}   /<[^>]*>$/{ gsub(/.*</,""); gsub(/(\+.*)?>/,""); to=$0; }'
std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
B::~B()@@Base
A::~A()@@Base
```

Note that the optimized build will have a different structure in assembly. You could just get anything before `atexit` that looks like a destructor:

```
$ objdump -CD a.out | awk '/__cxa_atexit@plt/{print to}   /~/ && /<[^>]*>$/{ gsub(/.*</,""); gsub(/(\+.*)?>/,""); to=$0; }'
std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
B::~B()@@Base
A::~A()@@Base
```

But anyway the method - parse the disassembly and get the function registered with `atexit`.

I've tested with:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A { ~A() { std::cout << "obi one kenobi"; } };
struct B { ~B() { std::cout << "hello there"; } };
volatile B b;
volatile A a;
```

compiled with `gcc -shared -fPIC`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not work. Somehow the structure of the static destructor section in my case is different, or disassembler gets confused with data sections. I did not find anything this way.  I will poke around a bit more.